# Adjoint of the Dual Map

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces, dual-maps

Given a linear map $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ between finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, we can define the dual map $f^*:Y^*\longrightarrow X^*$ by $f^*(\phi) = \phi\circ f$. In a paper on quantum computation that I'm reading the adjoint of the dual map is mentioned, it is given the name $f_*$. I'm trying to understand what $f_*$ looks like.

Here is my progress so far:
Clearly $f_*:X^*\longrightarrow Y^*$. Now let $(x_i)_i,(y_i)_i$ be bases of $X$ and $Y$ respectively and $(x_i^*)_i,(y_i^*)_i$ the dual bases, then
\begin{align*}
\langle y_j^*,f_*(x_i^*)\rangle_{Y^*} = \sum_k \langle y_j^*(y_k),f_*(x_i^*)(y_k)\rangle_{\mathbb{C}} = f_*(x_i^*)(y_j)
\end{align*}
where I used, that $y_j^*(y_k) = \delta_{jk}$. But since $f_*$ is the adjoint of $f^*$ we can also write
$$\langle y_j^*,f_*(x_i^*)\rangle_{Y^*} = \langle f^*(y_j^*),x_i^*\rangle_{X^*}$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
f_*(x_i^*)(y_j) &= \langle f^*(y_j^*),x_i^*\rangle_{X^*} = \langle y_j^*\circ f,x_i^*\rangle_{X^*} = \sum_l \langle y_j^*(f(x_l)),x_i^*(x_l)\rangle_\mathbb{C}\\
&= \overline{y_j^*(f(x_i))}
\end{align*}
where the overline denotes complex conjugation. This determines the evaluation at basis vectors. To find an expression for general $\phi\in X^*$,$y\in Y$ one could use linear combinations of the above. Now my question is: Is there a way of expressing $f_*$ that does not explicitely employ the use of a basis? Like for $f^*$ where we can write $f^*(\phi) = \phi\circ f$ without the need to define a basis

Comment: It's unusual to consider both the dual map and the adjoint map (as distinct notions) within the context of Hilbert spaces, especially finite dimensional Hilbert spaces. Are you sure that these are not synonymous in the context of the paper?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% certain. The paper is about dagger compact closed categories, and provides distinct categorical definitions of both concepts. I'm trying to work out some examples in the case of Hilbert spaces to make sure the definitions mentioned there coincide with the familiar ones. However I'm not sure what to make of the $f_*$ as defined above. You can find the paper [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/SelingerPositiveMaps.pdf) . See Definition 2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first read your question my intuition was that—because the dual and the adjoint of a Hilbert space operator are "equivalent" & because the adjoint is an involution ([i.e. $(A^\dagger)^\dagger=A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Properties))—the adjoint of the dual has to lead back to the original operator "somehow".
In order to turn this into a precise statement we certainly need the

> [Riesz representation theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53604): Every Hilbert space and its dual are related via the real-linear bijective map
> \begin{align*}
> \Phi_X:X&\to X^*\\
> x&\mapsto \Phi(x)
> \end{align*}
> which acts via $(\Phi(x))(x')=\langle x,x'\rangle$.

In quantum info notation one would express this via $\Phi(x)=\langle x|$. However, for this question it will be beneficial to assign an explicit symbol to this map.

With this we can—as a first step—relate the dual $f^*:Y^*\to X^*$ of a bounded linear map $f:X\to Y$ with its adjoint operator $f^\dagger:Y\to X$ (i.e. $\langle f^\dagger y,x\rangle=\langle y,fx\rangle$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$).
This yields the precise formulation of the initial claim that *"the dual and the adjoint are equivalent"*.

> **Lemma.** $f^*=\Phi_X\circ f^\dagger\circ \Phi_Y^{-1}$

*Proof.* Equivalently, we will show that $ f^\dagger\circ \Phi_Y^{-1}=\Phi_X^{-1}\circ f^*$. Given arbitrary $x\in X$, $y\in Y^*$ we compute
\begin{align*}
\langle (f^\dagger\circ \Phi_Y^{-1})(y),x\rangle&=\langle\Phi_Y^{-1}(y),fx\rangle=\big(\Phi_Y(\Phi_Y^{-1}y)\big)(fx)\\
&=y(fx)=(f^*\circ y)(x)\\
&=\big(\Phi_X(\Phi_X^{-1}(f^*\circ y))\big)(x)\\
&=\langle \Phi_X^{-1}(f^*\circ y),x\rangle=\langle (\Phi_X^{-1}\circ f^*)(y),x\rangle\,.\tag*{$\square$}
\end{align*}

Now if we could just "take the adjoint" of the above lemma we'd obtain a relation between $(f^*)^\dagger=:f_*$ and $(f^\dagger)^\dagger=f$. However, this adjoint would be on the level of dual spaces; hence this only makes sense once we know that the dual of a Hilbert space is a Hilbert space, as well. Indeed [this is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2041837) when equipping the dual with the inner product
\begin{align*}
\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{X^*}:X^*\times X^*&\to\mathbb C\\
(x_1,x_2)&\mapsto\langle\Phi_X^{-1}(x_1),\Phi_X^{-1}(x_2)\rangle_X\,.
\end{align*}

Again in physicists notation this would read $\langle \ \langle x_1|\,,\,\langle x_2|\ \rangle_{X^*}=\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$ for all $x_1,x_2\in X$.
Altogether we can now relate $f_*$ to the original $f$:

> **Proposition.** It holds that $f_*=\Phi_Y\circ f\circ \Phi_X^{-1}$.

*Proof.* By definition, $f_*=(f^*)^\dagger$ where $(\cdot)^\dagger$ is now the adjoint on the level of dual (Hilbert!) spaces. Using the above lemma we obtain
$
f_*=(f^*)^\dagger=(\Phi_X\circ f^\dagger\circ \Phi_Y^{-1})^\dagger
$. Now the adjoint acts on [compositions via](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Properties) $(A\circ B)^\dagger=B^\dagger \circ A^\dagger$ which implies
$$
f_*=(f^*)^\dagger=(\Phi_X\circ f^\dagger\circ \Phi_Y^{-1})^\dagger=(\Phi_Y^{-1})^\dagger\circ (f^\dagger)^\dagger\circ \Phi_X^\dagger=\Phi_Y\circ f\circ\Phi_X^{-1}\,.
$$
In the last step we used that [the adjoint is an involution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Adjoint_is_Involutive) as well as the redaily verified fact the Riesz isomorphism is a unitary transformation, that is, $\Phi^\dagger=\Phi^{-1}$.$\quad\square$

This is the precise formulation of our initial intuition that *"the adjoint of the dual has to lead back to the original operator"*.
Applied to any $\langle x|\in X^*$ (where $x\in X$) this proposition yields:
$$
\boxed{f_*(\langle x|)=\Phi_Y(fx)=\langle fx|}
$$
P.S. Be aware that at no point did we assume that our Hilbert spaces are finite-dimensional. Indeed the relation between $f_*$ and $f$ holds for arbitrary Hilbert spaces.